# Accessing other libraries from a JNI shared library - is it allowed?

Tags: java, maven, opencv, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am trying to develop an application that runs on STORM framework, and does face recognition using openCV. 
To start with, I created a simple project with maven ( a build management system), and run a simple JNI program with it. But, when i extend it to run a simple OpenCV program, it compiles fine, but gives a symbol lookup error, precisely when the JNI C++ code creates a MAT object in OpenCV. 
Here is the Native function.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ie_agisoft_Test.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ie_agisoft_Test_hello(JNIEnv *, jobject) 
{
cout << "Hello World\n" << endl;
cout << "salmost there \n" <<endl;

Mat img = imread("Sairam.jpg");
imwrite("Saicopy.jpg", img);

    cout << "read the image \n"<<endl;
}
```

Here is the error.
java: symbol lookup error: /tmp/libagisoft6338470031759870366.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6imreadERKSsi

I am using maven build system to build it, and I have a makefile that generates the .so file, and keeps it in the target/classes folder.

Could any one throw some light on why my application is not able to access other libraries despite compiling and linking fine??

Here is the complete makefile.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -c -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/include 
LDFLAGS=-fPIC -shared `pkg-config  opencv --cflags --libs`

SOURCES_DIR=src/main/c++
OBJECTS_DIR=target/c++
EXECUTABLE=target/classes/libagisoft.so

SOURCES=$(shell find '$(SOURCES_DIR)' -type f -name '*.cpp')
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:$(SOURCES_DIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o)

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
mkdir -p $(OBJECTS_DIR)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
rm -rf $(OBJECTS_DIR) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if i can provide anymore details to give you a clear picture.

---

Here is the make file output

```
mkdir -p target/c++
gcc -c -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/include  src/main    
/c++/ie_agisoft_Test.cpp -o target/c++/ie_agisoft_Test.o
gcc -fPIC -shared -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include  /usr/local   
/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/local
/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/local
/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /usr/local
/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local
/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local
/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local
/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local
/lib/libopencv_ts.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/local
/lib/libopencv_videostab.so   target/c++/ie_agisoft_Test.o -o target/classes/libagisoft.so
```

Comment: Please provide the complete, expanded command line executed by make to link the shared object. I suspect there is a -lopencv or similiar missing. What does pkg-config  opencv --cflags --libs print on your system?

Comment: Hello Matthias, I added the makefile in the description above. Thanks

Comment: Also, I sometimes get a different error, regarding the main JNI library itself, I am assuming that sometimes, randomly, my main JNI library it also not being able to link properly, Here is the error I get..

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ie.agisoft.Test.hello()V
 at ie.agisoft.Test.hello(Native Method)
 at ie.agisoft.App.main(App.java:11)

Answer (score 1):

Backticks don't work in Makefiles. Use `$(shell ...)` instead:

```
# LDFLAGS=-fPIC -shared `pkg-config  opencv --cflags --libs`
LDFLAGS=-fPIC -shared $(shell pkg-config  opencv --cflags --libs)

# manually inspect the value of LDFLAGS
$(error $(LDFLAGS))
```

Comment: The symbol lookup error still persists with this.     java: symbol lookup error: /tmp/libagisoft4557133975567625009.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6imreadERKSsi

Comment: I am pasting the output of the makefile in a seperate reply. please check the below answer.

Comment: @saipallavi, you do have a `System.loadLibrary("libagisoft")` call in the Java code, right? What's the output of `strace -eopen java ...`?

Comment: Yes,Scott, I do have system.loadlibrary() call, infact, it prints the statements from my C++ code. It is failing to loopup/link the symbols when I define the Mat object from opencv.   Also, I listed my makefile output below in a seperate comment. Is my linking wrong? should I link things like -lopencv etc, instead?

Comment: Inspect `readelf -D libagisoft.so` and `strace -eopen java ...` output, also try `LD_DEBUG=all java ...`.

Answer (score 1):

The -l options have to come after the .o files. Only those libraries are loaded of the ones specified that satisfy the unresolved references encountered so far, which are none before the object files. So you should place $(LDFLAGS) at the end of the command.

Comment: And you don't need the compiler flags on the linker command line, i.e. LDFLAGS=-fPIC -shared $(shell pkg-config opencv --libs) should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Matthias. Its working after the LDFLAGS are placed at the end of command line.